# How to declare a module deprecated in python

Tags: python, module, deprecated

How to declare a module deprecated in python?

I want a warning to be printed whenever a particular module is imported or any of its functions are called.

Comment: Add `print "Deprecated"` to `__init__` or add a decorator that does the same.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html

Comment: @ForceBru: How are you going to add a decorator to a module? And where are you going to find its `__init__` method?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You want to [`warn`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.warn) with a [`DeprecationWarning`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.DeprecationWarning).

Exactly how you call it doesn't matter that much, but the stdlib has a standard pattern for deprecated modules, like this:

```
# doc string, top-level comments, imports, __all__ =

import warnings
warnings.warn("the spam module is deprecated", DeprecationWarning,
              stacklevel=2)

# normal module code
```

See [the 2.7 `sets` source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/sets.py#l57) for an example.

Comment: I have used this piece of code in my __init.py__ of a specific module  on which I want to display as deprecated.  Its not working, neither its erring out. the function and class of that module can be easily accessible.