# How to properly deprecate a custom exception in Python?

Tags: python, exception, deprecated

I have custom inheriting exceptions in my Python project and I want to deprecate one of them. What is the proper way of doing it?

**Exceptions I have:**

```py
class SDKException(Exception):
    pass

class ChildException(SDKException):
    pass

class ChildChildException(ChildException):  # this one is to be deprecated
    pass
```

I want to deprecate the ChildChildException, considering the exception is used, raised and chained with other exceptions in the project.

Comment: Document it as deprecated.  Then, once everyone who uses it has had a chance to remove all uses of it, simply remove it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to declare a module deprecated in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093490/how-to-declare-a-module-deprecated-in-python)

Comment: @Prygan that looks like a good tool to use, but so far I think the answer by Alex Noname below better relates to my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a decorator which shows a [warning](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) `DeprecationWarning` category on each instantiation of exception class:

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("default", category=DeprecationWarning)

def deprecated(cls):
    original_init = cls.__init__
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        warnings.warn(f"{cls.__name__} is deprecated", DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
        original_init(self, *args, **kwargs)
    cls.__init__ = __init__
    return cls

class SDKException(Exception):
    pass


class ChildException(SDKException):
    pass

@deprecated
class ChildChildException(ChildException):  # this one is to be deprecated
    pass

try:
    raise ChildChildException()    
except ChildChildException:
    pass
```

```
app.py:7: DeprecationWarning: ChildChildException is deprecated
```

**Update**:
Also, you can create custom warning class and pass it to the warn function:

```
class ExceptionDeprecationWarning(Warning):
    pass
warnings.warn(f"{cls.__name__} is deprecated", ExceptionDeprecationWarning)
```

Comment: This issues the warning when the class is defined, not when the class is instantiated.

Comment: @AlexNoname unfortunately this approach did not show the deprecation warning for me. I am using Python 3.7.5 in case this matters. I ran your exact solution

Comment: @AlexNoname Sorry, I have to give more details, I noticed something. It did not show the warning if the exception was imported in the Python console like "from app import ChildChildException" and then use it as "raise ChildChildException()". However it was shown if I just ran your code as one script with "python app.py"

Comment: I updated answer and added `stacklevel=2` [parameter](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/warnings.html#warnings.warn). This is more correct because function wrapper is used.

Comment: @AlexNoname
That works now! One more thing - how'd you show the deprecated warning message when raising the class or an instance? So far it works only for the instance. That is "raise ChildChildException()" will show the warning and "raise ChildChildException" will not. I want to handle both cases

Comment: I changed [default](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/warnings.html#default-warning-filter) filtering of `DeprecationWarning`. And also added alternative solution.