# Add Warning printed when package is imported

Tags: python

Between version 1 and version 2 of a package, the package switched from imported modules as:

```py
from package1 import module1
```

to

```py
from package1.module1 import module1
```

I would like to add a warning about this when the package is imported in the new version. The docs reflect the change but I think most users won't be aware and could benefit from a warning.

Can I add a simple `print()` to my setup.py? Or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093490/how-to-declare-a-module-deprecated-in-python

Comment: that's helpful, I would argue that this is a different use case as the change has been made and  module1 can no longer be imported with a  warning. I need the warning to be general, not tied to a module that no longer exists

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to change setup.py to add a warning. This was the wrong place.

if you put the warning in **init**.py it will be raised when the package is imported.